# Error in R when using cluster analysis ("hclust" function)

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I want to do cluster analysis in R. So I create a distance matrix (Fig.1) below:

[image: Fig.1]

```
matrix_a <- data.frame(n1=c(0,1,11,5),n2=c(1,0,2,3),n3=c(11,2,0,4),n4=c(5,3,4,0))
```

Then I use the code below for cluster analysis:

```
result <- hclust(matrix_a,method="average")
```

However, an error occured:

```
Error in if (is.na(n) || n > 65536L) stop("size cannot be NA nor exceed 65536") : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Could anyone help me check out where was I wrong?

Comment: Try this: `hclust(as.dist(matrix_a), method = "average")`. The argument in `hclust` needs to be of class `dist`, not a matrix/data frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `?hclust` the `d` argument is described as:

> d
>     a dissimilarity structure as produced by dist.

The object `matrix` is not such an object.  In fact it is not even an R matrix.  It is a data frame.

Try the following.  We have given a more accurate name to the input and then converted it to a `dist` object as required.

```
DF <- data.frame(n1 = c(0,1,11,5), n2 = c(1,0,2,3), n3 = c(11,2,0,4), n4 = c(5,3,4,0))
hclust(as.dist(DF), "ave")
```

Comment: Thx! I checked my "value" in distance matrix before, not knowing because of "dist".